# Bit-bucket Jenkins webhooks invalid URL

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

I recently installed bit bucket plug-in(Version-1.1.8) in jenkins(Jenkins ver. 2.113). I configured a Jenkins webhook for a project on Bitbucket server by providing url http://ipaddress:port/bitbucket-hook/. When I tried to save I keep getting error invalid url. I am not sure why bit bucket is not accepting ip address. I assume it may be due to ipaddress not being exposed publicly.

Please help.

FYI:IP address is static and DNS is not configured for the server.

Comment: Is this Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or Bitbucket Server (self-hosted)? When you say "ipaddress not being exposed publicly", does that mean you're providing a private address (in 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, or 192.168.0.0/16)?

Comment: @JimRedmond Yes I am using Jenkins server's static private IP address. bitbucket.org is self-hosted

Comment: @JimRedmond Any idea on why my configuration is not working?

Comment: Not without further detail, sorry.

Comment: @JimRedmond I am using Bitbucket cloud. DNS name, Public IP are not setup yet.

Comment: @JimRedmond Do you need any further details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bitbucket Cloud (https://bitbucket.org/) is only accessible over public IPs, so it can only talk to other public IPs. If you're giving a private IP then Bitbucket won't have any way to reach it. (This is the intended nature of private IP spaces.)

You'll need to have a publicly-accessible IP, at the very least, so that Jenkins can receive incoming webhooks.